# Getting consent cookies for website login using python requests (CMP euconsent-v2)

Tags: python, http, cookies, python-requests, request

I'm trying to login to a website using python requests, however the webpage has a mandatory data protection consent form pop-up on the first page. I think this is why I cannot yet login, because posting your login credentials to the login URL requires these content cookies (which are probably dynamic).

After checking out the login post headers request (via inspection tools) it says it requires the cookies from a CMP, specifically a variable called euconsent-v2 (https://help.consentmanager.net/books/cmp/page/cookies-set-by-the-cmp), so my question is how to get these cookies (and/or other necessary cookies) from the website after accepting a consent pop-up, so I can login.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests

# Website
base_url = 'https://www.wg-gesucht.de'

# Login URL
login_url = 'https://www.wg-gesucht.de/ajax/sessions.php?action=login'

# Post headers (just a sample of all variables)
headers = {...,
           'Cookie': 'euconsent-v2=********'}

# Post params 
payload = {'display_language': "de",
           'login_email_username': "******",
           'login_form_auto_login': "1",
           'login_password': "******"}

# Setup session and login
sess = requests.session()
resp_login = sess.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

UPDATE: I have searched through all recorded requests from starting up the website to login and the only mention of `euconsent-v2` is in the response of this:

```
cookie_url = 'https://cdn.consentmanager.mgr.consensu.org/delivery/cmp_en.min.js'

referer = 'https://www.wg-gesucht.de'

headers = {'Referer': referer,
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}

sess = requests.session()
resp_init = sess.get(cookie_url, headers=headers)
```

But I still cannot get the required cookies

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be creating a session, then requesting all the sites that set the cookie that you need. Then with all the cookies in the session you make, you request the login page.

https://help.consentmanager.net/books/cmp/page/cookies-set-by-the-cmp

On the right hand side there is the location.

The image shown below, is just an example of what I mean. Its a random site/url that on the response header, it sets two cookies. A session will save all the cookies and then when you have all the mandatory ones, you make a request to the login page with post data.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I'm struggling to find any cookies in any response headers for this particular website

Comment: Open up developer tools, you can find all the requests there, enable preserve log and after the site loaded pause the inspection tool so you dont get stuff you dont need (like images,etc). Then go through each requests and look at the header, see if it has a set-cookie. 


Another option is:

- Use python selenium. I have been using it for a while and its the most easiest and fastest thing to do. If they have any protection like selenium detector you can easily bypass it with setting a useragent, etc. Use xpath as they are fast selectors

Comment: Yeah, I've had a good look through the requests. The cookies-headers required for the post to login page are no where to be found. I'll have a try with selenium

Comment: Selenium is the most easiest thing. If you need help I am more than happy to help you out.

Comment: Ended up developing it in Selenium, it handles cookies easily.